# Full width of graphics in GraphicsColumn

Tags: graphics, grid-layouts, alignment

I have a list of graphics which are all the same width, and I would like to combine them into a single Graphics object that has them all stacked on top of each other, column-style, without changing their widths. The help page for [GraphicsColumn](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsColumn.html) lists `Alignment->Full` as the option that would do that, but I'm having some trouble implementing it.

To take one of the examples in the help page, entering

```
GraphicsColumn[Table[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 10 i], {i, 1, 5}],
   Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]
```

will produce the following column.

[image]

I would expect changing `Alignment->Center` to `Alignment->Full` to provide a column with five circles of equal width. Instead, it returns the error message

> GraphicsGrid::optv: "Value of option Alignment->Full in GraphicsGrid[{{ [...] },{ [...] },{ [...] },{ [...] },{ [...] }},Alignment->Full,Frame->All] is not valid. "

This seems to me to be a bug, which came up [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/cYb6mKQ5WZw)/[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/cYb6mKQ5WZw), and which I will report shortly. I am running Mathematica 9.0.1.0 on Linux x86 (64-bit), Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS; I also observe the error on Mathematica 9.0.0.0 over Widows 7.

#### In the meantime, is there a practicable workaround?

---

To provide a bit more detail: the circles above are a MWE; my actual problem is more complicated. I have a table of similar plots, some of which have "stuff" on top added in using `FrameTicks`. A MWE that's closer to my actual situation is

```
GraphicsColumn[{
  ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200, 
   PlotLabel -> Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 100]],
  ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200]
  }]
```

[image]

---

The objects in the question are a MWE, my actual problem is more complicated. I have a table of objects which are *already* the same widths (and therefore the same `ImageSize`s), but they have different aspect ratios. Setting their `ImageSize`s constant would not do anything.

Perhaps a more representative example of my situation is:

```
GraphicsColumn[Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, i}]], {i, 1, 5}], 
  Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]
```

Comment: @Kuba That would produce a list of all the objects, with forced-equal widths. I need a Graphics object where the objects are in vertical succession and which respects their original (equal) widths.

Comment: p.s. On Win7 behaviour is the same.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm missing something, here is another try: `Column[Show[#, ImageSize -> {50, Automatic}] & /@ 
  Table[Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, i}]], {i, 1, 5}], 
 Alignment -> Center, Frame -> All]` (let's delete not important comments)

Comment: @Kuba That is almost there. Trying it out on my actual plots (see edit) still 'shortens' the first one. If I change `Automatic` to `Full` within `Show` the correct behaviour is obtained, modulo the spacings. I'll be happy to accept such an answer.

Comment: I have no patience to work with GraphicsGrid and friends and I usually choose Grid/Column. Is `Column` ok or you want first plot label to fit too? You can always `Rasterize` it.

Comment: Using `Column` produces, visually, the correct output, but I want the final object to be a single `Graphics`.

Comment: @episanty Try `Rasterize`.

Comment: @Anon yes, that also works.

Comment: I must be missing something. I can't see why it you don.t use `GraphicsColumn[Table[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, i]], {i, 1, 5}], Frame -> All]`. That makes all the disks the same size.

Comment: Further, your second example looks perfectly correct to me -- both graphics are made a big as can be to get them into the same size boxes. How would you change it to be satisfied?

Comment: @m_goldberg My real graphics are not `Disks`, as I have said; they are complicated `ContourPlot`s, one of which has additional plots 'tacked on' to the top using `FrameTicks`. All the plots *are* already the same width; the standard behaviour of `GraphicsColumn` is to resize one of the plots as in my second example. This is incorrect; the desired behaviour is to have both plots at the same width - as is made clear by both of them being set to `ImageSize->200`.

Comment: My conclusion after reading your question and all the comments carefully once more is that you are asking for something that `GraphicsColumn` can't and isn't intended to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard back from Wolfram, and this is indeed a documentation bug. As per their email,

> The issue you pointed out is indeed a documentation error in Mathematica. The value Full does not work with the Alignment option and I will file a report on this issue. The spacing could be set explicitly by the Spacings option.

I would contend that this is more of a missing feature but that's beside the point. I've been unable to use the Spacings to achieve what I want, but the workarounds provided by Kuba and Anon do work. Since they have not presented them as answers I will collect them here. m_goldberg's method of explicitly setting the height of each plot - and thus, I imagine, 'protecting' the aspect ratio - does also work.

The workaround by Kuba produces the closest output to what I originally intended, and to what I would expect from the option `Alignment->Full` as described in the [`GraphicsColumn`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GraphicsColumn.html) documentation. For some reason, prepending the list-to-be-GraphicsColumned with a `Show` command of the form `Show[#, ImageSize -> {200, Full}] &` does the trick. More fully, the code

```
GraphicsColumn[
 Show[#, ImageSize -> {200, Full}] & /@ {
   ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200, 
    PlotLabel -> Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 100]], 
   ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200]
 },
Spacings -> {0, -30}]
```

produces the output

[image]

with both graphics to the same width as they originally were.

Alternatively, as Anon points out, one can use a simple `Column` command, which does not alter the graphics' width and produces visually correct output. However, this has a disadvantage for me since I prefer a single `Graphics` object which I can print more easily. This can be achieved by encapsulating the `Column` within a `Rasterize` command (though this does entail a loss of the vector character of the graphics, on which an eye must be kept). In this option, the code

```
Rasterize[Column[{
  ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200, 
    PlotLabel -> Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 100]], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 200]
}]]
```

produces the output

[image]

though the vector character has been lost.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
GraphicsColumn[{ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ImageSize -> {200, 300}, 
  PlotLabel -> Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> 100]], 
  ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: graphic.png]

To get all the graphics in the `GraphicsColumn` expanded to full width, you must make sure that each image in the column has sufficient height to allow expansion to full width.